Implementation recommendations for task queues for multiprocessing tasks
I have a question regarding implementation suggestions. I have a function that runs on multiple cores (n cores), and I want to execute this function in parallel without oversubscribing my CPUs. For example, with four CPUs, I can run two functions that each require two CPUs simultaneously, or I can run three dummy functions where two use one CPU each and one requires two CPUs.
Are there any packages or suggestions you have that can provide this functionality?
The current code I have does achieve this. Are there any better implementations?

import multiprocessing
import os
import time
from concurrent.futures import as_completed, ProcessPoolExecutor


def dummy_function(process_count: int, duration: float):
    """A dummy functions that simulates parallel CPU work for the specified duration."""
    processes = []
    print(f"Start {os.getpid()} with {process_count} processes {time.time()}", flush=True)

    def dummy(duration: float):
        end_time = time.time() + duration
        while time.time() < end_time:
            pass
        return duration

    for _ in range(process_count):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=dummy, args=(duration,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print(f"End   {os.getpid()} with {process_count} processes {time.time()}", flush=True)

    return process_count


# Example configuration
cpus = 4
processes = [6, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2]
max_duration = 3

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpus) as executor:
    futures = []
    avail_processes = cpus

    futures_used = []

    for process_count in processes:

        if process_count > cpus:
            continue

        while process_count > avail_processes:

            for f in as_completed(futures_used):
                avail_processes += f.result()
                futures_used.pop(0)

        f = executor.submit(dummy_function, process_count, max_duration)
        futures.append(f)
        futures_used.append(f)
        avail_processes -= process_count  # Decrease available processes

    # Wait for remaining futures to complete
    for f in futures:
        f.result()


To prevent oversubscription, I have so far only implemented a simple implementation of limiting the worker in the process.

Prevent over-subscription by not having target functions spawn child processes, and make the pool with as many workers as the cpu has threads (plus or minus a few based on testing with your specific workload). Having multiple generations of process beyond parent and child is more difficult to manage, and makes it possible to leak zombie processes. This follows the "zen of python": Flat is better than nested. Nested levels of processes is an anti-pattern / code smell in my book.
